# Check the scanned input value is only numbers in C#

Tags: c#, validation, textbox

```
else if (vReadData.Length==14 && vReadData Is Numeric)
{
    if (txtIPLoad_MHEBarcode1.Text == "")
{
    txtIPLoad_MISBarcode1.Text = vReadData;
    txtIPLoad_MHEBarcode1.Focus();
}
else
{
    txtIPLoad_MISBarcode2.Text = vReadData;
    txtIPLoad_MHEBarcode2.Focus();
}
    mMessage("Scan", "Please scan the MHE Barcode!");
    return;
}
```

This is my code for validating a Textbox. I check the condition that the length should be 14 chars. I must also check that the input which comes in variable vReadData must be numeric (only numbers).
Please help me solve this.

I have tried using

```
 else if (Int64.TryParse(vReadData, out num))
```

but this is not helping me.

Comment: What is your question?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: what should be done to validate only numbers

Comment: Is `IsNumeric` not working? Looks like your missing or have too many curly brackets.  Might be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a *regular expression*?

```
 else if (Regex.IsMatch(vReadData, @"^[0-9]{14}$")) {
   // vReadData is a string of exactly 14 digits [0..9] 
 }
```

Explanation: we have to match two conditions

1. The string should be *exactly* `14` characters long
2. It should be a valid (non-negative) *number* (I doubt if any negative bar code exits)

After *combining* both conditions into *one* we can say that we're looking for a string which consist of `14` *digits* `[0-9]` (please notice, that we want `[0-9]` not `\d`, since `\d` in .Net means *any* digit, including, say *Persian* ones)

Tests:

```
string vReadData = @"B2MX15235687CC";
// vReadData = @"12345678901234";

if (Regex.IsMatch(vReadData, @"^[0-9]{14}$"))
  Console.Write("Valid");
else
  Console.Write("InValid");
```

Outcome:

```
InValid
```

If you uncomment the line you'll get

```
Valid
```

Comment: no sir i want to check if input value is only numbers

Comment: @Santhosh Raja: I'm sorry, don't follow you; could you provide some *examples* (both *positive* and *negative*)? For instance is `123,456,789,99` an accepted input? It contains numbers and has a length of 14 chars in total. Is `12345678901234` valid input? What about `00000000000000` (14 zeros)? Do you accept `3.14159265352` floating point number? Scientific notation? `1.23456789e123`? Negative `-1234567890123`

Comment: eg "B2MX" this should not satisfy the condition  "12345" this value should be accepted

Comment: @Santhosh Raja: I see, and my *current* regular expression rules this input out.

Comment: If the input is numbers ,condition must satisfy

Comment: @Santhosh Raja: are you looking for non-negative *numbers* which are **from** `1` **up to** `14` digits? Can the numbers start from zero? E.g. `00123`? Can the number be *negative* `-123`?

Comment: the length of input must be 14 digits, for that i used vReadData.Length==14    now one more condition is it must be numeric  eg (12345678901234)

Comment: It should satisfy both these condition

Comment: @Santhosh Raja: I've combined *both* condition into *one* (providing that the number should not be negative): you're looking for string which contains exactly 14 digits

Comment: will this work for "B2MX15235687CC" this kind of data it should not accept

Comment: @Santhosh Raja: and my current regular expression returns `false` for this input as expected

Comment: thanks sir it worked!!!!! @dmitry